# Is MPI_Igather thread-safe?

Tags: multithreading, mpi, openmp

I am trying to start a sequence of MPI_Igather calls (non-blocking collectives from MPI 4), do some work, and then whenever an Igather finishes, do some more work on that data.

That works fine, *unless I start the Igather's from different threads* on each MPI rank.
In that case I often get a deadlock, even though I call MPI_Init_thread to make sure that MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE is provided.
Non-blocking collectives do not have a tag to match sends and receives, but I thought this is handled by the MPI_Request object
associated with each collective operation?

The most simple example I found failing is this:

- given np MPI ranks, each of which has a local array of length np
- start one MPI_Igather for each element i, gathering those elements on process i.
- the i-loop is parallelized using OpenMP
- then call MPI_Waitall() to finish all communication. This is where the program hangs when setting OMP_NUM_THREADS to a value larger than 1.

I made two variants of this program: igather_threaded.cpp (the code below), which behaves as described above, and igather_threaded_v2.cpp, which gathers everything on MPI rank 0. This version does not deadlock, but the data is not ordered correctly either.

`igather_threaded.cpp:`

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <mpi.h>

#define PRINT_ARRAY(STR,PTR) \
    for (int r=0; r<nproc; r++){\
        if (rank==r){\
          for (int j=0; j<nproc; j++){\
            (STR) << (PTR)[j] << " ";\
          }\
          (STR) << std::endl << std::flush;\
        }\
        MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);\
    }

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int provided;
    MPI_Init_thread(&argc,&argv, MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE, &provided);
    if (provided!=MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE){
        std::cerr << "Your MPI installation does not provide threading level MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE, required for this program." << std::endl;
        MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, -1);
    }
    int rank, nproc;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&nproc);

    std::unique_ptr<double[]> M1(new double[nproc]);
    std::unique_ptr<double[]> M2(new double[nproc]);

    for (int j=0; j<nproc; j++) M1[j] = rank*nproc+j+1;

    PRINT_ARRAY(std::cout,M1);

    std::unique_ptr<MPI_Request[]> requests(new MPI_Request[nproc]);

    #pragma omp parallel for schedule(static) shared(requests)
    for (int j=0; j<nproc; j++){
        MPI_Igather(
            M1.get()+j,  1,  MPI_DOUBLE,
            M2.get(), 1, MPI_DOUBLE, j,
            MPI_COMM_WORLD, &requests[j]
        );
    }

    MPI_Waitall(nproc,requests.get(),MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE);

    if (rank==0) std::cout << " => "<<std::endl;
    PRINT_ARRAY(std::cout,M2);
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

My question is: is my code theoretically correct and this is a bug in OpenMPI (4.0.3 used here), or did I miss anything that disallows starting MPI_Igather calls by
multiple threads? I also tried it with Intel MPI with similar result.

To compile, I use OpenMPI 4.0.3 (configured to support MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE), gcc 11.2.0, and the command line

```
> mpicxx -std=c++17 -fopenmp -o igather_threaded igather_threaded.cpp
```

To run, I use

```
mpirun -np 4 --bind-to none env OMP_NUM_THREADS=4 env OMP_PROC_BIND=false ./igather_threaded
```

You may have to increase the number of MPI ranks and/or OpenMP threads, and/or run it several times because the exact behavior is not deterministic.

Comment: I do not think you can call `MPI_Igather()` on the same communicator by different threads at the same time. And even if you could, not to mention the same receive buffer is used by all the threads, your program would not make much sense at a semantic level.

Comment: I missed the fact different `root` are used so I take my comment about the semantic level back. That being said, I do not believe it is correct to have different threads calling `MPI_Igather()` simultaneously **and** on the same communicator (regardless the `root` argument value). But do not take my word for it, and feel free to ask what the right interpretation of the MPI standard is by asking the MPI forum directly (e.g. the `mpi-comments` - low volume - mailing list at https://lists.mpi-forum.org/mailman/listinfo/mpi-comments)

Comment: and where is igather_threaded_v2.cpp ?

Comment: I can confirm the out-of-order printing and the deadlock. Open MPI 4.1.0, libomp5, g++ 11.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MPI standard states in §6.12 that

> All processes must call collective operations (blocking and nonblocking) in the same order per communicator.

Two Igather operations with different root arguments are different collective operations. Your threads are issuing them without any synchronization on the same communicator. The resulting order may not be the same on all processes.

One solution would be to use different communicators for each thread (if all processes use the same number of threads). That way you have a single collective operation on each communicator and you can be sure that the right threads exchange data among each other. If you repeat that code multiple times, just create them up front and reuse them.

Answer (score 0):

In your scheme, because the collectives are started in different threads, they can be started in any order. Having different requests is not enough to disambiguate them: MPI insists that they are started in the same order on each process.

You could fix this by:

```
  #pragma omp parallel for schedule(static) shared(requests) ordered
  for (int j=0; j<nprocs; j++) {
    #pragma omp ordered
    MPI_Igather(M1.data()+j,  1,  MPI_DOUBLE,
                M2.data(), 1, MPI_DOUBLE, j,
                MPI_COMM_WORLD, &requests[j]);
  }
```

but that takes away most of the speedup you were hoping to get from threading.

Comment: The loop in which the MPI_Igather's are started is traversed exactly once, OpenMP just distributes the loop iterations over different threads.

Comment: Actually, I call MPI_Igather *nproc* times, not *nthread* times. And each call is associated with a different MPI_Request, so I don't see how this is wrong.

Comment: Hi Victor, the Igather's have different target process each, so each process receives exactly nproc elements into their buffer, right? Also, this is a drastically reduced MWE program, in the application each "element" is a chunk of several Gigabyte of data and dispatching all of them sequentially by a single thread becomes very slow.

Comment: Yes, I see what you're trying. I can confirm that it deadlocks and I don't see why.

Comment: @JonasThies ok, you now have two answers that explain it. I have a code fragment to make your scheme work.